# What is this wine set element?

Tags: wine

[image: mysterious element]

I have been wondering what is this wine set element - I can't think of a use to it and Google search showed other wine sets which didn't contain it (sometimes there was bottle opener holder in its place).

Here's a picture of the whole set:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a bottle opener holder?  It doesn't look exactly like any I've ever seen before, but it sure looks more like that than anything else I can think of.

Comment: Now that I think of it - it most probably is a holder for bottle opener. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a stand to hold your puller on a flat surface so it sits upright.

[image]